# Background image does not show up

Tags: html, css

I've tried the answers on 4 other S.O. questions but my image is still not showing up. 
I'm learning to code by going through [Dash at General Assembly](https://dash.generalassemb.ly/projects/build-your-own-personal-website).  However I'm building this project  using Sublime 3.

```
body{

    background-image: url("Southern California Sunset.jpg");
```

My html file and images are saved in the same folder. 
[image: location of html and images]

[image: My code]

Where I obtained the background image:

[Southern California Sunset.jpg](http://files.myopera.com/Mathilda%C2%B4s%20Wallpaper/albums/108188/Southern%20California%20Sunset.jpg)

Comment: try a / before the image name if %20 doesnt work out

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS syntax for background image is correct:

```html
background-image: url("Southern California Sunset.jpg");
```

You can replace each space with %20 which is the HTML URL encoding equivalent. But in a modern web browser this may not be necessary. You can also use camel case (that is, capitalization of the first letter of every word) without spaces or another naming convention to eliminate the spaces.

As long as the syntax is correct and the file is in the right place, the code should work properly.

You do, however, have a small (unrelated) syntax error in your code; this:

```html
<input type="email"; placeholder"Your email"/>
```

should be:

```html
<input type="email" placeholder"Your email" />
```

HTML is generally pretty forgiving of syntax errors. Still, it is best to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the spaces in the filename with `%20`:

```
background-image: url("Southern%20California%20Sunset.jpg");
```

In general, avoid spaces in file names.  Much easier.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip Paul. I changed the file name to: SouthernCaliforniaSunset and pasted the name into sublime to insure no typos. Did a hard refresh (ctrl alt v) but the background image is still not showing up, in Firefox or Chrome.   

Now the code is: 

'body{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica ; 
  background-image: url("SouthernCaliforniaSunset.jpg");'

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can get the developer tools up by pressing `ctrl-shift-I`.  If you then select the "network" tab, and then refresh, you can review all the network activity.  This will tell you if your CSS or your image is what's having problems being fetched, and more detail on what is actually being requested of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Like he said you should avoid using spaces when saving an image. I use the 'camel humps' method for all my coding. So instead of using spaces you capitalize the all the words. 
So instead of  'my example image text.jpg', it would be MyExampleImageText.jpg.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the file name to eliminate the spaces. Still didn't work. I even added another background image to the same html folder and  changed the image to background-grey-4.jpg.  Neither worked. Still no background image.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a picture size under 1 MB or 500 KB. This worked.

```
body { 
  background-image: url(yourfile.jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).